# How to make a public method in jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, methods, public

I've been using the below boilerplate for jQuery Plugin development which has been working great. But I'm not sure of the best way to make a "method" public.

```
           ;(function ( $, window, undefined ) {

              var pluginName = 'defaultPluginName',
                  document = window.document,
                  defaults = {
                    propertyName: "value"
                  };

              function Plugin( element, options ) {
                this.element = element;

                this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;

                this.init();
              }

              Plugin.prototype.init = function () {

              };

              $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
                return this.each(function () {
                  if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
                  }
                });
              }

            }(jQuery, window));
```

Thanks

Comment: window.fnName = function(){};

Comment: I'm not trying to make global function though. Id like to scope the method correctly.

Comment: JavaScript has no concept of property/method visibility. Scope is only evaluated in terms of global-scope / function-scope / lambda-scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only functions can be private / local, not a jQuery Plugin.

If you are using jQuery and trying to add your own (custom) function in jQuery, there are a best way `jQuery.fn.yourFunctionname = function(){}`, since jQuery is already in public scope so `jQuery.fn.yourFunctionname` is a public scope (no matter where you define your Plugin , will available for global use).

```
window.jQuery = jQuery;


$.fn.pluginName = function ( options ) {

    return this.each(function () {
    // code goes here
    });
}
```